# Objective C - determine class type at runtime

Tags: objective-c, class, runtime

In the interface I have this:

```
Animal*     myPet;
```

At runtime I may want myPet to be a cat or a dog, which are subclasses of Animal:

```
    id newPet;
    if(someCondition) {
            newPet = [[Cat alloc] initWithNibName:@"Cat" bundle:nil];
    } else {
            newPet = [[Dog alloc] initWithNibName:@"Dog" bundle:nil];
    }
    self.myPet = newPet;
```

Obviously this is incorrect, but I hope it's enough to show what I'm trying to do. What is the best practice for doing this?

Comment: And why do you say this is incorrect?

Comment: Note that doing lots of `isKindOfClass:` in your code is generally a sign that your are doing things the hard way.

Comment: @Dave - Because it doesn't work. If I try newPet.hunger = 50, I get the error: request for member 'hunger' in 'newPet', which is of non-class type 'objc_object*'

Comment: @bbum - I'm not using isKindOfClass in the code above. Would you care to share the "easy way"?

Comment: Generally, that'd be `Animal *newPet;` and `myPet` would be declared as an `Animal*`.  Beyond that -- no -- your are doing it right and I was just warning about future paths...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strongly type `newPet` as `Animal *` instead of `id`. `id` can hold a reference to an instance of any class, but properties cannot be used with it (the dot syntax requires a strongly typed lvalue.) Since both `Cat` and `Dog` inherit from `Animal`, this will be perfectly correct and valid.

If you're using two classes that *don't* share a common ancestor (past `NSObject`), then you should take a step back and rethink your design--why would instances of those two classes need to occupy the same variable?

Answer (score 10):

`isKindOfClass` is your friend:

```
[newPet isKindOfClass:Dog.class] == NO
```

Comment: I understand isKindOfClass, but I'm not sure how it fits in with my example code. I'm not trying to determine what kind of class the Animal is, I'm trying to create different kinds of Animals based on someCondition.

Comment: @sol: that "someCondition" you are looking for is exactly what The-Kenny posted (i.e. `[newPet isKindOfClass:Dog.class] == NO`).

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString *className = @"Cat";
Animal *myPet = [[NSClassFromString(className) alloc] init];
```

It's unclear what you are after, but if you want to create an instance of a class named by a string, this should do it.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone arriving from Google based on the title: "Determine class type at runtime", here are some useful things to know:

You can call the [`class`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/class) method on an `NSObject*` at run time to get a reference to its class.

```
[myObject class];
```

Take a look at these  methods too:

- [`isKindOfClass:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isKindOfClass%3a) - check if an object belongs to a class anywhere in its hierarchy.
- [`isMemberOfClass:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isMemberOfClass%3a) - check if an object belongs to a specific class.